# Indentation in RTF documents

Tags: rtf

I am working on an RTF document and need to justify certain text, there is 'increaseIndent' to accomplish this, but whenever I use it, either it doesn't work at all, like having no impact on the left aligned text or makes the text disappear altogether.

Can someone please guide me on how to overcome this issue?